# Coq: why can't I get an explicit witness out of an instance of Decidable?

Tags: coq

I start by defining a helper function for building instances of `Decidable P` given a proof of `{P} + {~P}`:

```
Require Import Coq.Classes.DecidableClass.

Definition derive_decidable : forall P : Prop, {P} + {~P} -> Decidable P.
intros P H; destruct H; 
[ apply (Build_Decidable P true) | apply (Build_Decidable P false) ];
intuition congruence.
Qed.
```

Now I define a silly type and give it a silly Decidable instance:

```
Inductive Color := red | green | blue.

Instance Color_eqdec (x y : Color) : Decidable (x = y).
apply derive_decidable; decide equality.
Qed.
```

Now I want to be able to use this instance to prove propositions about colors, but I'm getting a surprising result. After

```
Lemma green_neq_blue : green <> blue.
apply (Decidable_complete_alt _ (Color_eqdec green blue)).
```

I'm left with a goal of

```
Decidable_witness = false
```

So far so good. Now I expect to be able to discharge this goal by `compute; reflexivity`, but it's not working. After `compute`, my goal becomes

```
(let (Decidable_witness, _) := Color_eqdec green blue in Decidable_witness) = false
```

and no matter what I do, I can't seem to convince Coq to access the definition I gave in `Color_eqdec` for `Decidable_witness`. Why is computation getting stuck here, rather than beta-reducing `Color_eqdec green blue` and eventually simplifying to `false = false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to terminate your two instance definitions (`Color_eqdec` and `derive_decidable`) with `Defined.` in order to make their bodies transparent.

By default, when a proof is terminated with `Qed` the body is opaque and the term does not reduce. This is generally good for proofs because callers shouldn't depend on their contents. However, when using proof mode to construct terms that are in `Type` (namely `sumbool` and `Decidable` in your case), you actually want to compute with the body that the Ltac script constructed, so you should instead use `Defined` to make the resulting term transparent.